# How should I implement continent generation in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, fragment-shader

This is more of a general advice question regarding game development and Unity.

I am kind of a beginner in Unity, but I have some expirence in vulkan, opengl, godot, pygame, and making games in general, and I know C# pretty well.

I am working on an application in which the user can generate continents by clicking with the mouse on the surface of the sphere. Currently a continent is only displayed as a set of curved lines along the sphere. What I want is selectable, interactable contintents.

I was thinking 2 possible options:

- Create a shader that colors every pixel on the sphere that is inside of a given polygon (by polygon I mean a polygon projected to the sphere). From then on, I can manually do stuff with it, like set the color of the sphere to a brighter one on hover. To do this, in the shader I would need to project the points of the sphere to a 2d plane, (of course using a projection that does not ruin containment), and then check for every pixel if it is contained in the polygon.
  The possible problem with this is I have never written shaders in unity, and I don't know how much math support it has for this, since it is on the gpu. I would rather not implement rays and intersection detection from scratch.
- Create a seperate mesh for each continent, and that way it is easier to attach behaviour to it.
  The problem with this, is I have no idea how difficult it could be to procedurally generate a mesh along a sphere based on just some points. I was thinking a possible way to do this could be to (again) project the points of the sphere to a 2d plane, (of course, again, using a projection that does not ruin containment) and then we have the much more general problem of generating triangles for a 2d polygon. I don't know exactly how this step is done, but I fount the [ProceduralToolkit](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/procedural-toolkit-16508) asset for this, which can hopefully help. After generating the triangles, just project the points back.

My exact question is: Is there a simpler way to do this than what I described? If not, which one of these do you think is simpler to implement? I don't care about performance, I just need the simpler, easier to maintain solution. Also, any general advice is welcome.

Comment: Unless you're a shader guru go with meshes: https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/procedural-meshes/